# Are digits allowed in a knockout.js custom binding name?

Tags: netbeans, knockout.js, netbeans-7.4

I have an application with a custom binding declared like

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideContent2 = {
    init: ...,
    update: ...
}
```

and I use that in my html with (among other things)

```
<div data-bind="slideContent2: true"></div>
```

It works and produces no errors. Today I discover that the new knockout.js syntax checker in Netbeans 7.4 thinks that `<div data-bind="slideContent2: true">` is in error. It objects to the digit `2`. If I remove that, it thinks the name is fine. Looking around web examples, I haven't found an example of a digit used in the name of a custom binding.

Are digits legal in custom binding names? Is the Netbeans checker being overenthusiastic?

Comment: Digits are legal in JavaScript property names so also in binding handler names. Only the Netbeans checker is overenthusiastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Knockout point of view every valid JavaScript identifier name is a valid custom binding handler name.

So you can have digits in custom binding handlers. For the full identifier name reference you can check: [Valid identifier names](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers#Valid-identifier-names)

However from the Netbeans syntax checker point of view only letters are allowed in custom binding names.

For reference check out the source of [KODataBindLexer](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/8b41cfb576de/html.knockout/src/org/netbeans/modules/html/knockout/KODataBindLexer.java#l188) (I've added some comments)

```
case IN_KEY:
  if (!Character.isLetter(c)) { // the character 2 is not a letter
      if (c == ':') {
          state = State.AFTER_KEY;
          input.backup(1); //backup the colon
          return tokenFactory.createToken(KODataBindTokenId.KEY);
      } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
          state = State.WS_AFTER_KEY;
          input.backup(1); //backup the ws
          return tokenFactory.createToken(KODataBindTokenId.KEY);
      } else { // 2 is not a the colon and not a whitespace so it returns Error:
          state = State.INIT;
          return tokenFactory.createToken(KODataBindTokenId.ERROR);
      }
  }
  //stay in IN_KEY
  break;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for confirming my suspicions. I submitted a bug report: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=237736